# Swift - How to upload video to youtube unlisted?

Tags: swift, youtube, upload, swift4

I upload video to youtube from my app. But it is public now.

**My question is how can I upload video as unlisted ?**

**here is my upload func**

```
func postVideoToYT(videoUrl: URL, token: String,title:String,innoId:Int,videoTags:String,callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        do {
            let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
            let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: videoUrl)
            upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append("{'snippet':{'title' : '\(title)', 'description': ''}}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "snippet", mimeType: "application/json")
                multipartFormData.append(videoData, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
            }, usingThreshold: 1, to: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet")!, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        print("Post video to url --->\(response)")
                        if let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {
                            let videoId = json["id"] as! String
                            self.delayWithSeconds(1, completion: {
                                self.addVideo(innoId: innoId, videoKey:videoId, shortDesc: title, tagIds: videoTags)
                            })
                        }

                        callback(true)
                    }
                    break
                case .failure(_):
                    callback(false)
                    break
                }
            })
        }

        catch {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The privacy must be passed along with the snippet

```
"{'snippet':{'title' : '\(title)', 'description':' \(description)', 'tags': \(keywords)},'status':{'privacyStatus' : '\(privacyStatus)'}}".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
```

Added the privacy to your code below.

```
func postVideoToYT(videoUrl: URL, token: String,title:String,innoId:Int,videoTags:String,callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    do {
        let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: videoUrl)
        upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append("{'snippet':{'title' : '\(title)', 'description':' \(description)', 'tags': \(keywords)},'status':{'privacyStatus' : '\(privacyStatus)'}}".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "snippet", mimeType: "application/json")
            multipartFormData.append(videoData, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
        }, usingThreshold: 1, to: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet")!, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print("Post video to url --->\(response)")
                    if let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {
                        let videoId = json["id"] as! String
                        self.delayWithSeconds(1, completion: {
                            self.addVideo(innoId: innoId, videoKey:videoId, shortDesc: title, tagIds: videoTags)
                        })
                    }

                    callback(true)
                }
                break
            case .failure(_):
                callback(false)
                break
            }
        })
    }

    catch {

    }
}
```